# Html Firebase create new user not working

Tags: javascript, html, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Below is my code for my create/register user. I am using Visual Studio Code and Firebase.

For some reason, the code is not creating the new user. I can manually add users to the database however, I cannot create new users when I run the emulator and test the login.  I have enabled the Email and Password authentication in the Firebase console.

I am not sure what the problem is and would appreciate any insights from someone more skilled at coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF=8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Sign Up</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"     href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        margin: 0px;
    }
</style>



<div class "mb-5">
    <h3 class = "mb-3">Sign Up</h3>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Fullname" id="nameInp" class="form-control mb-3">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="emailInp" class="form-control mb-3">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="userInp" class="form-control mb-3">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="passInp" class="form-control mb-3">
    <button type="text" id="sub_btn" class="btn w-100 btn-outline-primary mb-3">Sign Up</button>
    <a href="login.html" class="badge badge-secondary py-1 w-100">Already Have An Account?</a>
</div>

<script type="module">

// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-app.js";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDj0QJk8Ptz0N_WjHg76iFhY3f2fBmStcM",
authDomain: "app-to-test-multiple-users.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://app-to-test-multiple-users-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "app-to-test-multiple-users",
storageBucket: "app-to-test-multiple-users.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "342422003892",
appId: "1:342422003892:web:7d0070e376d055c29737e1"
};
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    import { getDatabase, ref, set, child, get }
        from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-database.js";

    const db = getDatabase();

// references
    const name = document.getElementById('nameInp');
    const email = document.getElementById('emailInp');
    const username = document.getElementById('userInp');
    const pass = document.getElementById('passInp');
    const submit = document.getElementById('sub_btn');

    // validation
    function isEmptyOrSpaces(str){
        return str == null || str.match (/^ *$/) !== null;
    }

    function validation(){
let nameregex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
let emailregex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@(gmail|yahoo|outlook|)\.com$/; 
let userregex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}$/;

if(isEmptyOrSpaces(name.value)|| isEmptyOrSpaces(email.value)||        isEmptyOrSpaces(username.value)|| isEmptyOrSpaces(pass.value)){
    alert("you cannot leave any field empty");
    return false;
}
    
if (!nameregex.text(name.value)){
alert("Name should only contain alphabet letters!");
return false;
}

if(!emailregex.test(email.value)){
alert("enter a valid email!");
return false;
}
if(userregex.test(username.value)){
    alert("-username must be at least 5 characters long\n-username must not contain spaces");
    return false;
}

return true;

}

// registers to firebase
function RegisterUser(){
if (!validation()){
    return;
};
const dbRef = ref(db);

get(child(dbRef,"UsersList/"+username.value)).then((snapshot)=>{
if(snapshot.exists()){
    alert("Account already Exists");
}
else {
    set(ref(db, "UsersList"+ username.value),
    {
        fullname: name.value,
        email:email.value,
        username: username.value,
        password: encPass()

    })
    .then(()=>{
        alert("user added successfully");
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
        alert("error"+ error);
             })
        }
    });
}

// encryption
function encPass(){
var pass12 =CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(pass.value,pass.value);
return pass12.toString();
}

// events
submit.addEventListener('click', RegisterUser);

\</script\>



</body>
```